# recyclerView.isLayoutFrozen deprecated. What is the alternative in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How to stop the scrolling function of RecyclerView "temporarily" according to user input in a way that if the user wants the scroll functionality back, they can reactivate it. The most practical solution I could find is `isLayoutFrozen` in Kotlin.

However the function looks deprecated. So what is the better solution which can be applied to API 14 and onward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview?hl=sl#1.1.0-alpha02),
the `isLayoutFrozen` method is replaced with `isLayoutSuppressed`.
You can use it as `someRecyclerView.isLayoutSuppressed`.
Check out [API description](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#islayoutsuppressed).

If you are trying to assign the layout suppress property, use the `suppressLayout(boolean)` method.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer addresses the question. I had checked [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#isLayoutFrozen()) source and could not find the answer there. However, with `isLayoutSuppressed` I get the error "Val cannot be reassigned".

Comment: Are you trying to assign the layout suppress property?
If so, try the `suppressLayout(boolean)` method.

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thank you. Would you edit your answer or make a new one so that I can accept it?

Comment: Btw, I use "@" then your name but mention does not appear.